# Combine two plots in one graph using ciplot

Tags: stata

I would like to plot the means and confidence intervals of two variables into one graph. I used `ciplot` to do this for only one variable, but for two this code is not working.

On the internet I found that you could combine the plots as follows:

```
ciplot relative_ambition12 relative_ambition22, by(quota)
```

However, if I run this I get the error:

> no observations found

At the same time both of the following do produce graphs:

```
ciplot relative_ambition12, by(quota)
```

```
ciplot relative_ambition22, by(quota)
```

Does anyone know how I can combine these two graphs into one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to format your code properly and provide us with example data. Please read the Stata [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for details on how to ask Stata-related questions on here.

Comment: Aranka, if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 2):

The *community-contributed* command `ciplot` expects to work on the same set of observations for all variables specified in *varlist*.

For example, the following works:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
. generate price2 = price + 500

. ciplot price price2, by(foreign)
```

[image]

However, the following does not:

```
. replace price2 = . if foreign == 1

. ciplot price price2, by(foreign)
no observations
r(2000);
```

Both plots can be graphed separately (i.e. if one variable at a time is specified).

When you have different sets of observations, you can use the `inclusive` option to produce the desired output to the extent possible:

```
. ciplot price price2, by(foreign) inclusive
```

Comment: (+1) Credit for unearthing the undocumented option `inclusive` as well as diagnosing the problem generally.